# Can't call a web api service from Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, dotnet-httpclient

I have this web api service:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public bool Post(UserModel newUser)
 {
    return regRepo.AddUser(newUser);
 }
```

I want to call it from Xamarin.Forms project, so I made this:

```
   private void AddUser(object obj)
    {
        var user = obj as UserModel;
        var url = @"http://localhost:57615/api/UsersApi/";
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var json =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content);
     }
```

but it never call the service, I used Postman to make sure the URL is correct, and it works

**EDIT**

I changed the method signature to be `async` as klm_ suggested, but this error occurs:

> the Application is in break mode

[image]

Comment: How and where is `AddUser` being called on the client side?

Comment: If you are facing this issue in android then please check you have given Internet permission in AndroidManifest

Comment: I checked the internet permission, still not working.. this same code working in a console application, though!

Comment: if with this line var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content) application break then you can also try by changing HttpClient Implementation to AndroidClientHandler. You can do it from android project properties.

Comment: don't use localhost, use the IP of your server

Answer (score 1):

Try this (add **async** and **await**)

```
private async void AddUser(object obj)
{
    var user = obj as UserModel;
    var url = @"http://localhost:57615/api/UsersApi/";
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var json =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
 }
```

Comment: there's no details

Comment: Another thing that you can try is remove "async/await" and replace the last line with var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `obj` is a correct instance of your model.

```
 try
 {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var model = obj as UserModel ;
    var url = @"http://localhost:57615/api/UsersApi/";
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return message;
 }
 catch (Exception x)
 {
 // message
 }
```